# No integration option available

Tags: stellaris

I have had a "subject" for a while, with the integration option showing a date to mark the 10 year period. Once the period was elapsed, the option is still unavailable saying simply that I can't integrate it.

Does it have to do with ethos? I have collectivist, militarist, and xenophile.

Answer (score 5):

As you said where you originally post your question, your subject was not a vassal but a protectorate. It has nothing to do with ethos.

Protectorate can not be integrated into your empire. However, when they reach 40% of your technology, they are converted into vassal and can now be integrated.

Be careful, if you get a new protectorate in mid-game, they will probably never be able to reach the 40% as they start with basic tech, even if you give them free research boost.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I started realizing these aspects indeed. 
So it's kind of hopeless right? I'm less than 2 centuries into my game, but the tech difference with my protectorates who actually entered the space age during the game will never be reduced enough right? 
Plus I do not see any option in diplomacy or trade to help them science-wise, I've been giving some resources but I don't think that will help.. Again, i do not know if that's because of ethos or because of the huge tech gap.  
Kind of ruins the point of elevating pre-space species in the goal of integrating them later, no?

Comment: @user3930111 I've had protectorates take more than a century to catch up enough, but eventually they do. It helps if they have some room to expand. They usually don't catch up with only one system. I usually throw energy and minerals at them whenever I fill up on one, and use ongoing deals to balance my production.

Comment: There are several mods which allow for the integration of protectorates ub case you don't want to wait.